# Why is Gnu Screen slow to scroll in a vertical split region?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

On my Ubuntu, Gnu screen is very slow when scrolling in a vertically split region (the one you create with CTRL-A |.

But Tmux doesn't have this problem. Why is this?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards